# On the usage of "allow"

Tags: word-usage

> 1. Nanxiang aside, the best Xiao long bao have a fine skin, allowing them ___ (lift) out of the steamer basket without **allowing them tearing or spilling** any of their contents.
>    （ From a test）
>    The given answer: to be lifted

Collins suggests the grammar pattern for "allow" should be "V n to-inf", rather than "V n ing" (allowing them tearing or spilling), so I'm considering it could be a mistake.

1. Are there any other form possible for that blank？
2. Does the bold part make sense？

Xiao long bao:  a kind of food, also known as soup dumpling(s).

---

After reading the comments and answers, there arise another question.  If the revised version is:
1a. ... allowing **them** to be lifted out of the steamer basket without **tearing or spilling** any of their contents.

What is the understood subject of "tearing or spilling..."？
Do soup dumplings tear (by themselves)？

Comment: The bold part doesn't make sense: it appears that **allowing them** has been accidentally repeated there.

Comment: @KateBunting  I find the original context(https://www.seriouseats.com/best-bites-in-china-chinese-food-drink)  doesn't include "allowing them".  Actually, that's part of the reason I asked.  But I wasn't sure if it could be a deliberate revision by the text maker.

Comment: What @KateBunting said. It would be *possible* to retain the noun but not the participle *(...without **them** tearing or spilling...)*, but I doubt that was ever the intention. Either way, it looks to me like a meaningless transcription error - it doesn't tell us anything useful about syntactic affordances for ***to allow*** (apart from the obvious; if you randomly repeat words in an utterance, they probably won't work! :)

Comment: 1. "to be taken" is possible - but the hint says to use the verb "lift". 2. No it doesn't make sense. It's definitely an error. Delete "allowing them".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Without those two words, what is the understood subject then?   More details are added to the main body of the question.

Comment: The syntactic breakdown ambiguous/unspecified. You could parse it like I said - (elided) ***them*** referring to the dumplings themselves (*These dumplings tear easily* uses the dumplings as the *subject* of the verb). OR you could assume an elided ***you*** (or ***the cook***, or similar, tearing the dumplings). It makes no difference to the overall meaning. Native speakers wouldn't normally think about this - nor would they have an opinion as to which *kind* of noun could be included at that point in the text - the text is easily understood if you simply ignore that *syntactic* ambiguity.

Comment: Lots of "subject + verb + object" can be reformulated to have the *object* become the "autonomous" subject ("doing something *to itself*"). It often happens with food; *I'm baking the bread in the oven / The bread is baking in the over*, or *I'm boiling the potatoes / The potatoes are boiling*. The coffee is brewing, etc., etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for explaining so clearly.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any other form possible for that blank？

To be honest, i have no idea what "Nanxiang" or "Xiao long bao" is, so I will argue purely on *grammatical* grounds. Any sense the sentence might have will not  necessarily be preserved:

"to be lifted" is the passive voice. Generally, where there is passive voice there also might be active voice, therefore "to lift" should (at least grammatically) be possible. Here is another example:

> I am going ___. (bite)

can have two solutions:

> I am going *to bite*. (active)
> I am going *to be bitten*. (passive)

> Does the bold part make sense?

Yes. "to allow" means not only "to give your consent" but also "to make possible".

> I allow you to watch the movie.

Means I give my consent to you doing so.

> Four-wheel-drives allow for faster acceleration.

The 4WDs were not asked for their consent, they just make it possible.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that Xiao long bao is  a kind of food, also known as soup dumpling(s).  People lift them  with chopsticks when eating.

Comment: Do you think "allow them lifted" would work？

Comment: @ForOU: no, that won't work. As I said it is either passive or active: either the subject *does* something or *something is done* with/to it. Hence, "allow them *to be* lifted". "Allow them lifted" would mean *make it possible (allow) that they are in a state where they are off the ground*. But here, you refer to the *action of lifting*, not the state they might be in afterwards.